# Roxygen2 and Rstudio, not show the references in Rd.file

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools, roxygen2

I am trying to add the references in my documents via Rdpack.
But in my Rd.file, it can't show the reference correctly. I don't know why it happens.

[image]

i follow the steps : https://cran.rproject.org/web/packages/Rdpack/vignettes/Inserting_bibtex_references.pdf .

- I have created the inst/REFERENCES.bib.
- Also add Imports: Rdpack RdMacros: Rdpack s to file ‘DESCRIPTION’
- and add @importFrom Rdpack reprompt in my roxygen2
- I use the \insertRef{key}{packagename} and
  #' @references
  #'  \insertAllCited{} in my roxygen

Any help? thank you